# Overlaying views in React Native

Tags: react-native

Im trying to make a dropdown similar to the image below and im wondering if such a thing is possible. That is because:

- `overflow` defaults to `hidden` on android and that since zIndex doesnt work all that well.
- `zIndex` doenst work all that well, views need to be in the proper order in order to draw over others normally

The only scenario that i can think of to make this work right now is to use something like `onLayout` and manually calculate the position of where it is that the dropdown needs to display and then render it at the top level in absolute positioning. I worry this might look rather hybrid-y but havent tried it yet.

Other ideas?

[image]

Comment: I think you can check following implementation https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/tree/master/src/components

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use zIndex to achieve this behavior, but zIndex has to be applied to adjacent views to work cross platform:

```
render(){
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
      <View style={{ zIndex: 2 }}>
        <YourDropdownButton />
      </View>
      <View style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
        <YourNormalButton />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

[Here is a snack showcasing this with my own custom drop down](https://snack.expo.io/rkWGyz527)

Comment: Unfortunately thats the things, views arent adjacent in this case as the PickerItem elements are nested within parents. That's If by adjacency you mean siblings in the same parent and not simply being on the same depth level

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use the native dropdown, it renders correctly and works as intended on all platforms?

Either way, you can always position it absolutely yes. I've done something like this and it works, but you can have some glitches if the list gets longer and it needs to scroll. Also, you would have to implement proper closing (clicking outside, and on the main element, closing after choosing the options. etc).

Comment: Im not sure i know what a native dropdown is in the context of React Native. If you're speaking of the `Picker` this has a lot of limitations.

Also another thing is, in my use case there's overlap happening between elements, this isnt simply a dropdown over nothing. zIndex in RN doesnt work too well if things arent rendered in a very specific order. I've managed to made this work with a single overlay such as a dialogue + scroll including what you mentioned with clicking outside etc but the scenario im describing here is very different because of the two bullets i added on the description.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/peacechen/react-native-modal-selector ?